# XML parsing issue in WinStoreApp

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

i just stuck in an issue when ever i parse my XML like this using Xdocument :

```
 XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(datafromxml);

 var data = from query in xmldoc.Descendants("Chapter")

    select new MyEntityclass
         {
            Sampledata = (string)query.Element("SubChapter")

         };
```

i got only one tag inner value from this. i.e from the first tag value only. remaining are skipped.

My XML is like :

```
<Chapter>
    <SubChapter ChapterID="1"><![CDATA["Some data here 1"]]></SubChapter>
    <SubChapter ChapterID="2"><![CDATA["Some data here 2"]]></SubChapter>
    <SubChapter ChapterID="3"><![CDATA["Some data here 3"]]></SubChapter>

</Chapter>
```

when i checked in a debug i just got the value of "chapterid : 1". please help me to sort out this. thanks

Comment: `<SubChapter ChapterID="1"> ... </Verse>` If that's a typo then fix it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry by mistake.fixed !

Answer (score 1):

Your query now only retreives (iterates) the outer node.

You need something like (untested)

```
var data = from query in xmldoc.Descendants("Chapter")
           from chapter in query.Elements("SubChapter")  // note the 's'
           select new MyEntityclass
           { 
             Sampledata = (string)chapter
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = xmlDoc.Root
                 .Elements("SubChapter")
                 .Select(x => new MyEntityclass { Sampledata = (string)x });
```

Comment: Right, assuming that "Chapter" is the root. Note that the OP uses Descendants to get to that level.b Also, you're missing the new EntityClass